# Plot size of each node according to dictionary

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory

So far I have the following code:

```
source = ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0']
destination = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']

FB_network_graph = pd.DataFrame({ 'from':source, 'to':destination})
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(FB_network_graph, 'from', 'to')

plt.figure(figsize = (100,100))
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

I want to plot a graph whereby node '0' has a size of 7 and node '1'-'7' has a size of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to adjust the `node_size` according to the [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)). For that you can define a dictionary from the result of  [`G.degree`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.degree.html) and set the size according to the corresponding node degree by looking up the dictionary:

```
scale = 300
d = dict(G.degree)
nx.draw(G, node_color='lightblue', 
        with_labels=True, 
        nodelist=d, 
        node_size=[d[k]*scale for k in d])
```

[image]

Alternatively you could just define your custom dictionary, to set the corresponding node sizes in `node_size`. For this specific case with something like:

```
d = {str(k):1 for k in range(1,8)}
d['0'] = 7
```

Comment: Thank you!! it works. Can i also ask if there is any library/method in python that helps to draw a histogram with x-axis = node degree and y-axis = fraction of nodes with degree x. Is it also possible to plot a power law curve on the same histogram with various power law exponent ?

Comment: The advisable thing would be for you to ask a new question for this. Please do ping me here when you do, I'll be happy to answer :) @ZhenKai

Comment: i have posted the question in a new tab, the tab as follows:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099850/python-histogram-graph-and-power-law-best-fit-line-all-in-one-graph
Thank you!